# Up to 1 billion objects? Can I even use Vector for that?

Tags: c++, memory-management, object-oriented-analysis

I have a problem in which I am told that the user can enter up to 1 billion as the total number of locations.  I then use Haversine to calculate the distance and find the closest location to the starting location.

Normally, I would just use a vector container, or even dynamically allocate memory and I would be done.  However, the 1 billion really throws me off and I don't know how to best handle it.

I thought to just create an object in loop and copy it to another object.  This seems to work with some limited testing.  I did not build any unit tests for this part yet. I thought it better to ask if I was understanding things correctly.

**ignore my wierd name spacing stuff...I was messing around.  The distances and classes/functions I wrote all work properly/as expected.

```
#include "Location.h"
#include "UserInput.h"
#include "DistanceCalculator.h"

int main()
{
    locationnamespace::Location farthest, closest;
    //returns location object from getting input
    locationnamespace::Location startLocation = getLocationInput();
    int totalLocations = getTotalLocations();

    for (int i = 0; i < totalLocations; i++){
        locationnamespace::Location endLocation = getLocationInput();
        std::cout << endLocation.toString();
        if (i==0){
            closest = endLocation;
            farthest = endLocation;
        }
        //returns true if endLocation is closer than the closest.
        if(isCloser(startLocation, endLocation, closest)){
            closest = endLocation;
        }

    }

    std::cout << "Closest: " << closest.toString();

    return 0;
}
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, my variable for endLocation always has the same memory address on the stack.  I am then creating a Location object in the loop.  This object gets copied to my Location object 'closest'.  Any object that does not get copied gets destroyed when it falls out of scope, correct?
So I am reusing the same variable by creating a new object at the same memory location and then just moving it to another memory location outside of scope?

1. What would be the correct approach for something like this?
2. Is my understanding above true?  Or am I confused?

Comment: On most modern 64 bit systems, `vector` can handle a billion elements. You might have problems getting enough primary storage to hold the whole thing all at once, but that's a detail at a lower level than `vector` cares about.

Comment: *my variable for endLocation always has the same memory address on the stack.* Maybe and to be honest almost certainly, but not guaranteed and ultimately irrelevant so long as the compiler can prove that whatever it does instead [is more efficient and doesn't affect the observable behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: So long as `Location` can be safely copied or moved, what you've presented looks good to me. It's simple and easy to read, so see what the compiler does with it

Comment: If vector is dynamically allocated and would have a problem holding the thing all at once, wouldn't any dynamic allocation on the heap have the problem also? @user4581301

Comment: Heap, stack, however else memory might be represented, it doesn't matter. On a modern system with virtual memory the CPU is going to swap data around in the many layers of storage trying to make sure what you need now is where it needs to be. If it needs to move data not currently in use to a larger-but-slower type of memory to get room for what you need now or soon in a faster memory, the CPU just does it. If you're only using the top ten K of the stack, the bottom of the stack might be pushed down to the hard drive or further in order to make sure what's needed now is available now.

Comment: Obviously if you are using huge amounts of memory, you want to minimize time spent swapping data to and from something like the hard drive, but the rules for this are pretty basic. Quoting Stroustroup: "don’t store data unnecessarily, keep data compact, and access memory in a predictable manner."

Comment: So first off,  is there any incidental information in the data point that the computations don't care about and you can leave out to make the data point smaller? Then you may have a billion points of data, but do you need them all in the `vector` all at the same time? Can you just sort of roll the buffer, read in a few process them, store the result and then discard in order to free up space to read in a few more? Can you sort the data so data points that will be used together will be stored together?

Comment: Handy reading: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/

Comment: In your case, you may have a billion locations to scan, but at the end of the day, you only care about one, the closest, so you are doing the right thing by rolling through the whole input set and only keeping the one you care about and the one you're currently processing in memory.  There might be some wee errors in there I'm not seeing, but your overall logic is correct.

Comment: That's great that I'm on the right track.  I did not realize that some of the stack can be pushed to the hard drive!  That's awesome!